# Stop wordpress image compression with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, jpeg, image-compression

It appears that Wordpress compresses images that you upload about 82% when it generates thumbnails. Is it possible to stop this?

I've tried:

`add_filter(‘jpeg_quality’, function($arg){return 100;});`

And

`add_filter('wp_editor_set_quality', function($arg){return 100;});`

in functions.php in both my child theme and parent theme (one at a time) and it doesn't work. Does this code even work in php7?

The only workaround I've found is to upload directly to my server NOT through Wordpress and link to those spots, but that's a real pain.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The comment to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13602331/1213708 states - *For the sake of later viewers, the 'jpeg_quality' filter has been deprecated in favor of 'wp_editor_set_quality'*

Comment: I've also tried that 

add_filter('wp_editor_set_quality', function($arg){return 100;});

Also didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the thumbnail generated size in my theme settings and it worked, so the wp_editor_set_quality must have worked.